# RESTEASY003765: Response is closed error while reading Wildfly 19 management API Using Java 11

Tags: wildfly, java-11

Both my client and server are running on adopopenjdk 11.0.9.101.
I'm running this on Windows 10 Home edition.
My client tries to connect to the management REST API. (All of this has worked on Java 8 in the past)

On the server side I have a standard Wildfly 19 server with some mail smtp properties .

```xml
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="some.smtp.server" port="465"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
```

A management user was created called "admin".

The client has a fairly small main method which tries to read these properties.

```java
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.digest("admin", "admin");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(feature);
        
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9990/management")
    .path("/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp")
    .queryParam("operation", "resource");
Response r = target
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .get();
Map<String, Object> smtpResponse = r.readEntity(new GenericType<HashMap<String, Object>>() { });
System.out.println(smtpResponse);
```

This results on the server side in the following output:

```
11:57:37,054 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (management I/O-2) Matched prefix path /management for path /management/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp
11:57:37,054 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (management I/O-2) Setting authentication required for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /management/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp}
11:57:37,056 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (management I/O-1) Matched prefix path /management for path /management/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp
11:57:37,056 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (management I/O-1) Setting authentication required for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /management/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp}
11:57:37,226 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (management I/O-2) Matched prefix path /management for path /management/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp
11:57:37,227 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (management I/O-2) Setting authentication required for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /management/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp}
11:57:37,227 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (management task-1) Authenticated as admin, roles []
11:57:37,230 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (management I/O-1) Matched prefix path /management for path /management/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp
11:57:37,230 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (management I/O-1) Setting authentication required for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /management/socket-binding-group/standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding/mail-smtp}
11:57:37,231 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (management task-1) Authenticated as admin, roles []
11:57:37,249 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.io] (management I/O-2) Error reading request: java.io.IOException: De externe host heeft een verbinding verbroken
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.read(NioSocketConduit.java:289)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:158)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:136)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:59)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)

11:57:37,250 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.io] (management I/O-1) Error reading request: java.io.IOException: De externe host heeft een verbinding verbroken
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.read(NioSocketConduit.java:289)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:158)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:136)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:59)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.7.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
```

On the client side I can see this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: RESTEASY003765: Response is closed.
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.abortIfClosed(AbstractBuiltResponse.java:308)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.abortIfClosed(ClientResponse.java:290)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:59)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.readEntity(AbstractBuiltResponse.java:270)
    at be.cprtest.wildfly.Main.main(Main.java:74)
```

This is my client's pom.xml file

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.bramgadeyne</groupId>
    <artifactId>WildflyManagementTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you have two clients on your class path? The pom shows both RESTEasy and Jersey clients.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, it appears to work with only the jersey-client libraries. The difficulty is that I need resteasy for some other parts of the application and I need to use digest authentication. Do you know how I can enable Digest Authentication in RestEasy?

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this. I'm guessing you're using Jersey because of the lack of helpers for digest authentication in RESTEasy. I've filed https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-2856 as a feature request for this.